# Fs says there is not file but there is

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So I have a file that is doing

```
const cmds = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./cmds.json'));
```

and the file that I am running this in is in the same folder as cmds.json but it says it cant be found? (if I give it the full location it works but I want to have it so that it works like this too)
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNTVR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `./` to `__dirname + '/'`

```js
const cmds = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cmds.json'));
```

`__dirname` is a Node.js variable that represents the path of the current directory.

Comment: @AMTitan If it worked, could you mark this the accepted answer ?

Comment: I was going to but I had to wait 10 mins to set yours as correct but now I did